# Rails & postgresql, notify/listen to when a new record is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, publish-subscribe

I'm experimenting & learning how to work with PostgreSQL, namely its Notify/Listen feature, in the context of making Server-Sent Events according to this [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/06/real-time-rails-4-using-server-sent-events-with-authy-onetouch.html).

The tutorial publishes `NOTIFY` to the `user` channel (via its `id`) whenever a `user` is saved and an attribute, `authy_status` is changed. The `LISTEN` method then yields the new `authy_status` Code:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
after_commit :notify_creation

def notify_creation
  if created?
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |connection|
        execute_query(connection, ["NOTIFY user_?, ?", id, authy_status])
    end
  end
end

def on_creation
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |connection|
    begin
      execute_query(connection, ["LISTEN user_?", id])
      connection.raw_connection.wait_for_notify do |event, pid, status|
        yield status
      end
    ensure
      execute_query(connection, ["UNLISTEN user_?", id])
    end
  end
end

end
```

I would like to do something different, but haven't been able to find information on how to do this. I would like to `NOTIFY` when a user is created in the first place (i.e., inserted into the database), and then in the `LISTEN`, I'd like to `yield` up the newly created user itself (or rather its `id`).

How would I modify the code to achieve this? I'm really new to writing SQL so for example, I'm not very sure about how to change `["NOTIFY user_?, ?", id, authy_status]` to a statement that looks not at a specific user, but the entire `USER` table, listening for new records (something like... `["NOTIFY USER on INSERT", id]` ?? )

**CLARIFICATIONS**

Sorry about not being clear. The `after_save` was a copy error, have corrected to `after_commit` above. That's not the issue though. The issue is that the listener listens to changes in a SPECIFIC existing user, and the notifier notifies on changes to a SPECIFIC user.

I instead want to listen for any NEW user creation, and therefore notify of that. How does the Notify and Listen code need to change to meet this requirement?

I suppose, unlike my guess at the code, the notify code may not need to change, since notifying on an id when it's created seems to make sense still (but again, I don't know, feel free to correct me). However, how do you listen to the entire table, not a particular record, because again I don't have an existing record to listen to?

For broader context, this is the how the listener is used in the SSE in the controller from the original tutorial:

```
  def one_touch_status_live
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    @user = User.find(session[:pre_2fa_auth_user_id])
    sse = SSE.new(response.stream, event: "authy_status")
    begin
      @user.on_creation do |status|
        if status == "approved"
          session[:user_id] = @user.id
          session[:pre_2fa_auth_user_id] = nil
        end
        sse.write({status: status})
      end
    rescue ClientDisconnected
    ensure
      sse.close
    end
  end
```

But again, in my case, this doesn't work, I don't have a specific `@user` I'm listening to, I want the SSE to fire when any user has been created... Perhaps it's this controller code that also needs to be modified? But this is where I'm very unclear. If I have something like...

`User.on_creation do |u|`

A class method makes sense, but again how do I get the listen code to listen to the entire table?

Comment: As far as I know, `after_save` is called before the transaction is committed to the database. Hence, id is not available. You can instead use `after_commit` which runs after the transaction is complete. This ensures that the id is now available for you.
More information is available at https://flexport.engineering/how-to-safely-use-activerecords-after-save-efde2b52baa3

Comment: Check this: [A PostgreSQL Notification Example](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1206065/A-PostgreSQL-Notification-Example)

Comment: hi sorry i've added clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `after_commit` instead of `after_save`. This way, the user record is surely committed in the database

> There are two additional callbacks that are triggered by the completion of a database transaction: after_commit and after_rollback. These callbacks are very similar to the after_save callback except that they don't execute until after database changes have either been committed or rolled back.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#transaction-callbacks

Actually it's not relevant to your question, you can use either.

Here's how I would approach your use case: You want to get notified when an user is created:

```rb
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :notify_creation

  def notify_creation
    if id_previously_changed?
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |connection|
        self.class.execute_query(connection, ["NOTIFY user_created, '?'", id])
      end
    end
  end

  def self.on_creation
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |connection|
      begin
        execute_query(connection, ["LISTEN user_created"])
        connection.raw_connection.wait_for_notify do |event, pid, id|
          yield self.find id
        end
      ensure
        execute_query(connection, ["UNLISTEN user_created"])
      end
    end
  end

  def self.clean_sql(query)
    sanitize_sql(query)
  end

  def self.execute_query(connection, query)
    sql = self.clean_sql(query)
    connection.execute(sql)
  end
end
```

So that if you use

```rb
User.on_creation do |user|
  #do something with the user
  #check user.authy_status or whatever attribute you want.
end
```

One thing I am not sure why you want to do this, because it could have a race condition situation where 2 users being created and the unwanted one finished first.

Comment: hi sorry i've added clarifications

Comment: hi @james `after_create` is almost same as `after_save` and the sql statement is not committed to the database at the point `after_create` callback is triggered, could you change to `after_commit` and post the result here?

Comment: ok so i changed to `after_commit` but honestly, that's not really what the question is about... i've added more detail in clarifications, would you mind reviewing again?

Comment: @james I'm sorry about the confusion, I checked your code, tutorial and question carefully and tested in my own local machine. Please see the updated answer if it helps. Thanks

Comment: I see your point about the race condition... so my use case is very simple (and this feels super complicated!) I literally am using the SSE to display an alert on the webpage. It's not for validation or anything like that. Because it's just a helpful alert, if 2 users were created at the same time, I don't really care if one alert fires and over-rides the other, or both fire. I just want to make sure, however, that 2 users do end up getting created, and this somehow doesn't affect that.... do you see that as being an issue?

Comment: I see @james. You want to have notification when user is created. Did you try my edited answer? Please let me know the result

Comment: Yes! It appears to be working, thank you so much for providing the detailed code and going through the tutorial as well. Last question - do you see the race issue as a big concern? Again I just want to fire at least 1 alert, I don't care if only 1 fires, or if both do. However, I of course want to make sure that the SSE or the notify/listen on one user creation doesn't somehow interrupt the creation of other users

Comment: If you want to make sure the user1 receives user1 created event then you need to update the notify channel. Something like `created_user_#{str}` where `str` is the unique element to user1 during creation (session_id, etc.). And update method `self.on_creation(unique_str)`, to listen with `"LISTEN user_created_#{unique_str}"`. Then you can do this `User.on_creation(unique_str) do |user|`. This will make sure user1 see user1's notification while user2 is seeing user2's notification.

If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted answer. Thank you. I also learn something today :D

Comment: Ah I see, I don't care about having distinct alerts, just want to make sure that having the notify doesn't cause creation issues if multiple users are created at the same time!

Comment: a quick follow up. My design specs have changed,  now the race condition is important. In your comment above, the unique `str` is treated like an idempotency key right? So user1 on <b>their</b> page will see their alert & user2 on <b>their</b> page will see their alert. However, my use case is a <b>single</b> admin page, where I want to see alerts for all users that are created. Initially 1 alert was fine if multiple users come in as a group, but now I do need individual alerts. How would you modify code? I can award more bounty on this answer or start a new question

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60897923/rails-postgresql-notify-listen-whenever-a-new-record-is-created-on-an-admin-d