# Rails & postgresql, notify/listen whenever a new record is created on an admin dashboard without race condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, publish-subscribe, server-sent-events

I have an admin dashboard where I want an alert to be fired whenever a user is created (on a separate page). The code below works, however, there's a race condition. If 2 users are created very close together, it will only fire once.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_commit :notify_creation, on: :create

  def notify_creation
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |connection|
      self.class.execute_query(connection, ["NOTIFY user_created, '?'", id])
    end
  end

  def self.listen_to_creation
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |connection|
      begin
        execute_query(connection, ["LISTEN user_created"])
        connection.raw_connection.wait_for_notify do |event, pid, id|
          yield id
        end
      ensure
        execute_query(connection, ["UNLISTEN user_created"])
      end
    end
  end

  def self.clean_sql(query)
    sanitize_sql(query)
  end

  private

  def self.execute_query(connection, query)
    sql = self.clean_sql(query)
    connection.execute(sql)
  end
end

class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live

  def update
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    sse = SSE.new(response.stream, event: 'notice')
    begin
      User.listen_to_creation do |user_id|
        sse.write({user_id: user_id})
      end
    rescue ClientDisconnected
    ensure
      sse.close
    end
  end
end
```

This is my first time doing this, so I followed this [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/06/real-time-rails-4-using-server-sent-events-with-authy-onetouch.html), which like most tutorials are focused on updates to a single record, rather than listening to an entire table for new creation.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you send only one update at once and then the request ends. If you make a request at the AdminsController#update. You have one subscriber waiting for your notification. Look at this block

```rb
begin
  execute_query(connection, ["LISTEN user_created"])
  connection.raw_connection.wait_for_notify do |event, pid, id|
    yield id
  end
ensure
  execute_query(connection, ["UNLISTEN user_created"])
end
```

As soon as you get one notification, the block yields and then you close the channel. So if you are relying on frontend to make one more connection attempt once it gets the result, if a record gets created before you start listening to the channel again in the new connection, you won't get a notification as there was no listener attached to Postgres at that time.

This is sort of a common issue in any realtime notification system. You would ideally want a pipe to frontend(Websocket, SSE or even LongPolling) which is always open. If you get a new item you send it to the frontend using that pipe and you should ideally keep that pipe open as in case of Websockets and SSE. Right now you are kind of treating your SSE connection as a long poll.

So your code should look something like

```rb
# Snippet 2
  def self.listen_to_creation
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |connection|
      begin
        execute_query(connection, ["LISTEN user_created"])
        loop do 
          connection.raw_connection.wait_for_notify do |event, pid, id|
            yield id
          end
        end
      ensure
        execute_query(connection, ["UNLISTEN user_created"])
      end
    end
  end
```

But this will run into a problem where it will keep thread alive forever even if the connection is closed until some data comes to thread and it is encounters an error while writing back then. You can choose to either run it a fixed number of times with short lived notify intervals or you can add sort of a hearbeat to it. There are two simple ways of accomplishing a hearbeat. I will add them as quick hack codes.

```rb
# Snippet 3
def self.listen_to_creation(heartbeat_interval = 10)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |connection|
      begin
        execute_query(connection, ["LISTEN user_created"])
        last_hearbeat = Time.now
        loop do 
          connection.raw_connection.wait_for_notify(heartbeat_interval) do |event, pid, id|
            yield({id: id})
          end
          if Time.now - last_heartbeat >= heartbeat_interval
            yield({heartbeat: true})
            last_heartbeat = Time.now
          end
        end
      ensure
        execute_query(connection, ["UNLISTEN user_created"])
      end
    end
  end
```

In the above example you will at least be sending something in the pipe every heartbeat_interval seconds. So, if the pipe closes it should error out and close the pipe thus freeing up the thread.

This approach kind of adds controller related logic to model and if you want to hold postgres notify without a time interval, the other thing that you can do to do a heartbeat is, just launch a thread in the controller itself. Launch a thread in the controller method that sleeps for heartbeat_interval and writes `sse.write({heartbeat: true})` after waking up. You can leave the model code the same as Snippet 2 in that case.

Also, I added the other things to watch with SSEs with Puma & Rails in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637013/rails-app-hangs-when-theres-a-server-sent-event-sse-that-requires-database-ac/61000047#61000047) to your other question:

Comment: This was a good explanation! I am very new to SSE. Unfortunately neither snippet worked, but I also have a feeling that there is some tie between this and my other question. I am feeling a bit out of my depth here, I'm getting the feeling it's not something I can quickly resolve so I will study PG notify/listen a bit more in detail. I honestly thought this would be much more straightforward! Like, even the heartbeat approach feels inefficient, because at regular intervals you're pumping out useless `{heartbeat:true}`, I would've thought there's an easier way to pump out data only when needed

Comment: heartbeat is only required because of how Rails and Puma are dealing with connections you hold for a long time. You can choose to skip it, but that just adds the issue of hanging connections. If you want to avoid heartbeats with SSE/WS type connections your best bet would be to choose a specific server for this.

Comment: Also, I would love to know what happens when you use snippet 2.

Comment: When I first tried this 2 days ago I put a `puts` right before the `yield id`. The puts there got fired. But on the front end I'd only get one alert come through. I don't remember if I put a `puts` in controller before `sse.write` to see what was being written. Sorry. Today I've spent time trying it again, can't even duplicate results from 2 days ago, literally nothing happens. A `puts` before `sse.write` doesn't fire. I feel like it's the thread/pool issue, which again, I need to actually dive into and learn. Even trying to fresh page gives me a `run out of connections` error